# How to create item entries in a dynamo db table using cloud formation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I am having a cloud formation template with which i am deploying lamdba function and a dynamo db table into a third party aws account now i wanted to create entries in the created dynamo db table using the same cloud formation template. Can anyone help ?

I have tried with the following cloud formation template but it is not working -

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: dynamodbAccessRole
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - dynamodb:*
            Resource: "*"
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - logs:*
            Resource: "*"
  InitFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: >
          const AWS = require("aws-sdk"); const response = require("cfn-response"); const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
              var params = {
                TableName: event.ResourceProperties.DynamoTableName,
                Item:{
                  "id": "abc123"
                }
              };

              docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                  response.send(event, context, "FAILED", {});
                } else {
                  response.send(event, context, "SUCCESS", {});
                }

                // Send signal to WaitCondition
                const cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation();
                const signalParams = {
                  UniqueId: event.ResourceProperties.WaitConditionId,
                };

                cloudformation.signalResource(signalParams, function(signalErr, signalData) {
                  if (signalErr) {
                    console.log("Error sending signal to WaitCondition:", signalErr);
                  } else {
                    console.log("Signal sent to WaitCondition");
                  }
                });
              });
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Timeout: 60
  DynamoDB:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: id
        AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: id
        KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1

  InitWaitCondition:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition
    DependsOn: InitFunction
    Properties:
      Handle: !Ref InitWaitConditionHandle
      Timeout: '300'
      Count: 1

  InitWaitConditionHandle:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle

  InitializeDynamoDB:
    Type: Custom::InitFunction
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt InitFunction.Arn
      DynamoTableName: !Ref DynamoDB
      WaitConditionHandle: !Ref InitWaitConditionHandle
```

Comment: What issue do you face?

Comment: I am getting error in Wait condition - WaitCondition timed out. Received 0 conditions when expecting 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CloudFormation for that. This would be in the form of a Lambda function which would use AWS SDK to populate your DynamoDB table.

Comment: I am already using a custom resource lamdba function in it